# Oracle - SELECT CASE WHEN syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, jasper-reports

I'm developing a JasperSoft report, and I'm currently getting a ORA-00905 error in my underlying Oracle SQL. The query editor doesn't seem to like this code. Is this syntactically correct, or is this erroneous? I can't seem to find out why I'm getting the ORA-00905 error as it's not pointing at any specific line in my code in JasperSoft Studio.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN $P{groupResManagerInvManager} = 'RESMGR'
    THEN r.resource_manager_key ELSE i.investment_manager_key END manager_key,
    CASE WHEN $P{groupResManagerInvManager} = 'RESMGR'
    THEN r.resource_manager ELSE i.investment_manager END manager,
    r.resource_key AS resource_key,            
    r.resource_name AS resource_name,
    te.investment_name AS investment_name,
    te.incident_name AS incident_name,       
    te.task_name AS task_name,
    t.wbs_sequence AS wbs_sequence,
    tln.task_status AS task_status,
    te.charge_code AS charge_code,
    te.input_type_code AS input_type_code,
    teln.time_record_type AS time_record_type, 
    CASE WHEN $P{firstDayOfWorkWeek} IS NULL
        THEN cfg.week_start_day
        ELSE CASE WHEN $P{firstDayOfWorkWeek} = 'WeekdayMonday' THEN 1
        WHEN $P{firstDayOfWorkWeek} = 'WeekdayTuesday'   THEN 2
        WHEN $P{firstDayOfWorkWeek} = 'WeekdayWednesday' THEN 3
        WHEN $P{firstDayOfWorkWeek} = 'WeekdayThursday'  THEN 4
        WHEN $P{firstDayOfWorkWeek} = 'WeekdayFriday'    THEN 5
        WHEN $P{firstDayOfWorkWeek} = 'WeekdaySaturday'  THEN 6
        WHEN $P{firstDayOfWorkWeek} = 'WeekdaySunday'    THEN 0
                 ELSE 1 END                    
            END AS week_start_day,              
    tp.start_date AS period_start_date,
    tp.finish_date  AS period_end_date,
    tsln.timesheet_status AS timesheet_status,   
    SUM(CASE WHEN $P!{weekDay} = 1  THEN pf.time_hours ELSE 0 END) day_1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN $P!{weekDay} = 2  THEN pf.time_hours ELSE 0 END) day_2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN $P!{weekDay} = 3  THEN pf.time_hours ELSE 0 END) day_3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN $P!{weekDay} = 4  THEN pf.time_hours ELSE 0 END) day_4,
    SUM(CASE WHEN $P!{weekDay} = 5  THEN pf.time_hours ELSE 0 END) day_5,
    SUM(CASE WHEN $P!{weekDay} = 6  THEN pf.time_hours ELSE 0 END) day_6,
    SUM(CASE WHEN $P!{weekDay} = 7  THEN pf.time_hours
    WHEN $P!{weekDay} = 0  THEN pf.time_hours ELSE 0 END) day_7               
FROM   dwh_tme_period tp
       INNER JOIN  dwh_tme_sheet ts ON tp.time_period_key = ts.time_period_key
       INNER JOIN  dwh_res_resource r ON ts.resource_key = r.resource_key
       INNER JOIN  dwh_tme_sheet_ln tsln ON  tsln.timesheet_key = ts.timesheet_key
                                         AND tsln.language_code = $P{ppmUserLanguage} 
       INNER JOIN  dwh_tme_entry te ON ts.timesheet_key = te.timesheet_key
       INNER JOIN  dwh_tme_entry_ln teln ON  teln.timeentry_key = te.timeentry_key
                                         AND teln.language_code = $P{ppmUserLanguage} 
       INNER JOIN  dwh_tme_entry_facts pf ON  te.timeentry_key = pf.timeentry_key
       INNER JOIN  dwh_cfg_settings cfg ON 1=1              
       INNER JOIN  dwh_cmn_period c ON  c.period_key = pf.period_key   
                                    AND c.period_start_date BETWEEN $P!{dwhDBSchema}.dwh_cal_trunc_date_fct(tp.start_date)
                                                            AND     $P!{dwhDBSchema}.dwh_cal_trunc_date_fct(tp.finish_date)                                                
                                    AND c.period_type_key = 'DAILY'                                                                                     
       LEFT  OUTER JOIN dwh_inv_assignment a ON te.assignment_key = a.assignment_key
       LEFT  OUTER JOIN dwh_inv_task t ON te.task_key = t.task_key
       LEFT  OUTER JOIN dwh_inv_investment i ON te.investment_key = i.investment_key 
       LEFT  OUTER JOIN dwh_inv_task_ln tln ON  t.task_key = tln.task_key
                                            AND tln.language_code = $P{ppmUserLanguage} 
WHERE  1=1
AND    r.employment_type_key <> 0
AND    r.resource_type_key = 0     
AND   (r.is_active = CASE WHEN $P{includeInactiveResources} = 1 THEN r.is_active ELSE 1 END)                                        
AND   (i.is_active = CASE WHEN $P{includeInactiveInvestments} = 1 THEN i.is_active ELSE 1 END)     
AND    $X{IN, r.employment_type_key, employmentTypeKey_1}
AND   ($X{IN, 'all', investmentTypeKey_1} OR $X{IN, i.investment_type_key, investmentTypeKey_1})
AND    $X{IN, r.resource_key, resourceKey_1}
AND    $X{IN, r.resource_manager_key, resourceManagerKey_1}
AND    $X{IN, i.investment_key, investmentKeyNoOBS}
AND    $X{IN, i.investment_manager_key, investmentManagerKey_1}
AND    $X{IN, ts.timesheet_status_key, timesheetStatusKey_1}
AND  (($X{IN, tp.time_period_key, timePeriod}) 
       OR    ($X{IN, -1, timePeriod}
              AND    tp.time_period_key = (SELECT a.time_period_key
                                           FROM   dwh_tme_period a 
                                           WHERE (SELECT $P!{dwhDBSchema}.dwh_cal_date_add_fct(b.start_date,'DAY',-1)
                                                  FROM   dwh_tme_period b
                                                  WHERE  $P!{dwhDBSchema}.dwh_cal_trunc_date_fct($P{today}) BETWEEN b.start_date AND b.finish_date) BETWEEN a.start_date AND a.finish_date))
       OR    ($X{IN, -2, timePeriod}
              AND    tp.time_period_key = (SELECT a.time_period_key 
                                           FROM   dwh_tme_period a 
                                           WHERE  $P!{dwhDBSchema}.dwh_cal_trunc_date_fct($P{today}) BETWEEN a.start_date AND a.finish_date))
       OR    ($X{IN, -3, timePeriod}
              AND    tp.time_period_key = (SELECT a.time_period_key
                                           FROM   dwh_tme_period a 
                                           WHERE (SELECT $P!{dwhDBSchema}.dwh_cal_date_add_fct(b.finish_date,'DAY',1)
                                                  FROM   dwh_tme_period b
                                                  WHERE  $P!{dwhDBSchema}.dwh_cal_trunc_date_fct($P{today}) BETWEEN b.start_date AND b.finish_date) BETWEEN a.start_date AND a.finish_date)))
AND   ($P{resourceOBSUnitKey_1} IS NULL
       OR     
       r.resource_key IN (SELECT DISTINCT obsm.resource_key
                          FROM   dwh_res_obs_mapping obsm
                                 INNER JOIN dwh_cmn_obs_hierarchy obsh ON obsm.obs_unit_key = obsh.child_obs_unit_key
                          WHERE  obsh.parent_obs_unit_key = $P{resourceOBSUnitKey_1}))                                        
AND    EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   dwh_res_security_v
               WHERE  user_uid = $P{ppmUser}
               AND    resource_key = r.resource_key)
GROUP BY i.investment_manager_key, i.investment_manager, r.resource_manager_key, r.resource_manager,
         r.resource_key, r.resource_name, te.investment_name, te.task_name, t.wbs_sequence, tln.task_status, te.charge_code, te.input_type_code,
         cfg.week_start_day, tp.start_date, tp.finish_date, tsln.timesheet_status, te.incident_name, teln.time_record_type
```

For any unfamiliar with Jasper reports, the $P{} is a parameter/placeholder.

Thanks

Comment: you'd better to share whole SQL Select statement I think. Syntax seems right so far.

Comment: Exactly. ORA-00905 is a *missing keyword* error. There's nothing *missing* here (or, should we say, there's a *lot* missing).

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I've added the entire SQL statement.

Comment: @Littlefoot I've added the entire SQL statement.

Comment: Did you issue `SQL> show error` ?

Comment: I am not familiar with Jasper reports placeholder substitution, but if it is trying to replace those with strings (ie bind variables) Oracle is going to fail as it does not understand schema and column names unless they are hard parsed in the SQL.Are you able to inspect the SQL that is submitted to the database post-substitution?

Comment: The query you posted is not relevant, as it is input for Jasper. You must check the real query send from Jasper to Oracle. Try Jasper logging or `10046 Oracle trace`. Alternative approach is a *binary search* - i.e. cutting the query in half still reproducing the error.

Comment: @doodlebob You can enable logging at Jaspersoft Studio or enable log4j at test Java code, for example - to view query with parameters value

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the use of IN, such as on line?

```
$X{IN, r.resource_key, resourceKey_1}
```

Comment: No, that is the correct use of $X{} in JasperSoft. I've ran other reports with the same syntax and they work correctly.